# Org-mode: C-c a is undefined but I have set key in config

Tags: org-mode

I am a new user of emacs org-mode. I am getting an error when trying to get into agenda mode:

```
C-c a is undefined
```

My `~/.emacs` looks like this:

```
(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
```

And I believe the files are in the correct directory structure because if I `M-x` into `org-agenda` manually, the agenda correctly shows the calendar items in my file. I am starting from the file:

GTD_todo.org in ~/org/

And my config is:

.emacs in ~/org/

I am using Cygwin64 on a Windows 10 machine. Thanks!

Comment: This should work. Do your other bindings work - `C-c l`, `C-c c` etc.

Comment: hmmm, no, none of them work. I initially thought that maybe GTD_todo.org wasn't using that .emacs file as it's config. Is that possible if the org-mode agenda is displaying calendar items from GTD_todo.org?

Comment: Actually-- that is it. My emacs is using ~/.emacs as it's config, not ~/org/.emacs as I thought. I think I can probably search how to change where emacs looks for its config file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help. I realized ~/org/.emacs was not actually my configuration file, emacs was using ~/.emacs, which contained an agenda reference to ~/org/GTD_todo.org as an agenda file but not the global shortcut keys.

So, org-agenda was showing the correct agenda files but could not use the hotkeys. The edits I was making to ~/org/.emacs were not actually doing anything.

Thank you!